# How to get meta value in wp_attachment_metadata

Tags: arrays, wordpress

want to get wp_attachment_metadata in my own way. I want to get the file name :

```
a:5:{s:5:"width";i:500;s:6:"height";i:500;s:4:"file";s:25:"2016/08/sprite_1500ml.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:5:{s:9:"thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:25:"sprite_1500ml-150x150.jpg";s:5:"width";i:150;s:6:"height";i:150;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:6:"medium";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:25:"sprite_1500ml-300x300.jpg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:300;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:14:"shop_thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:25:"sprite_1500ml-180x180.jpg";s:5:"width";i:180;s:6:"height";i:180;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:12:"shop_catalog";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:25:"sprite_1500ml-300x300.jpg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:300;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:11:"shop_single";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:25:"sprite_1500ml-400x400.jpg";s:5:"width";i:400;s:6:"height";i:400;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}}s:10:"image_meta";a:12:{s:8:"aperture";s:1:"0";s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";s:1:"0";s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";s:1:"0";s:3:"iso";s:1:"0";s:13:"shutter_speed";s:1:"0";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:11:"orientation";s:1:"0";s:8:"keywords";a:0:{}}}
```

Well, I am stuck. I don’t know how to separate that array. Anyone knows how to separate that array in order I can get the file name (url file).

my code now :

```html
$command = $_GET['command'];
switch ($command) {
    case 'list_product':

        $loop = new WP_Query( 
                array(
                        'post_type'    => 'product'
                    )
                ); 
        if( $loop->have_posts() ) :

            $data = array( "api_status" => 1, "api_message" => "success");
            $meta = array();
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                    $meta[] = array(
                        "id"            => get_the_ID(),
                        "post_name"     => get_the_title(),
                        "stock_status"  => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_stock_status', true ),
                        "price"         => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_price', true ),
                        "reguler_price" => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true ),
                                                "image"         => get_post_meta( get_the__ID(), '_wp_attachment_metadata', true ),
                    );
            endwhile;
        endif;
        echo  json_encode($meta);
        break;
```

i mean when i use :

```
"image"         => get_post_meta( get_the__ID(), '_wp_attachment_metadata', true ),
```

my result doesnt show anything

what improvement in my code so its can work like what i want ?

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18463/how-to-extract-data-from-a-post-meta-serialized-array) helps.

Comment: iam sorry, first, when i use `"image"         => get_post_meta( get_the__ID(), '_wp_attachment_metadata', true ),`i mean doest show data anything.. have u help me what i need to do ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an image url, I show you another way to to this. I suppose you want the post thumbnail of a spicific post.

```
// First we get the image id
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ); 

// Then we get the image data, we will get an array with some informations
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, 'large' );

// the image url is the first index of this array
$image_url = $image[0];
```

In this example you get the image url for the `large`version. If you want antoher size, just change it to e.g. `meidum` or `full`. Read the [documentation of wp_get_attachment_image_src()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) for more details.

This code must be placed inside the loop. Make sure that `get_the_ID()` **returns the current POST ID**. Make also sure that the POST **have a post thumbnail**.

Basically you can get an image url if you have an ID of an attachmend post (image).

Comment: i get response null, have u show me where i need input this code in my code ? i think i wrong where i put this code thanks